# Creating a temporary reference, vs reusing? which is better?

Tags: java, performance, object, reference, coding-style

Say I have a method I call mutiple times (say 10 adverage per application run).

I iterate through a list, find an element with the proper ID and then pass that element as a parameter for another method.

Does it make any difference whether this reference is a field (member) for the class which I update each time with the new element, or whether I just make a new temporary reference? Code example below

```
for (element e : list) {
    if (e.getID() == searchID) {
        //reassigning value of the reference in the class
        mElementToRemove = e;
        break;
        }
 }
 list.remove(mElementToRemove);
```

VS.

```
 for (element e : list) {
    if (e.getID() == searchID) {
        //(new reference)
        Element mElementToRemove = e;
        break;
        }
 }
 list.remove(mElementToRemove);
```

Perhaps there isn't a difference in terms of which is better style or which is more performant?

Thanks!

*edit . I mistyped the bottom example. For full context I meant:

```
 private void removeThisId(int searchID) {
 Element ElementToRemove = e; 
 for (element e : list) {
    if (e.getID() == searchID) {
        //(new reference)
        mElementToRemove = e;
        break;
        }
 }
 list.remove(mElementToRemove);
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by `(new reference)` - is that just a comment? By reference you mean a local variable?

Comment: meant it to be a comment, typed it too quickly, apologies. Yes it would be a local variable I suppose but it isn't a primative, it is a reference to an object in the list.

Comment: When you can use both, always choose local variables over fields. They are faster, easier to reason about and less likely to cause errors. Your method using field has race condtion, memory leak and is not reentrant. Using local variable avoids all of this with no added cost.

Comment: The code of the first and third are *identical* except for your comment... and the second doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example, the `Element` will be out of scope by the end of the loop, so that won't even compile.

Have you thought about using an `Iterator`?

```
for(Iterator<Element> i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
     if(i.next().getId() == searchID) {
         i.remove();
     }
}
```

No concurrent modification errors, no having to declare temp variables.

And if you are guaranteed to only have at most one `searchID` in the List (why not use `Set` then?), then you can exit early by inserting `break;` after the remove call.

Comment: Thanks for the help todd. I didn't mean to declare in that small of scope. Inside the list are Objects, in this case, they are IconSets which contain a string title, int id, and int usageNumber. I am currently getting the IconSet and then calling its getId() method to return it's id and compare to the search ID.

Comment: There, changed to what I think you are using.

Comment: the iterator interface looks handy. I think that's what I will do. Looks clean and with good style. Thanks todd.

Comment: I agree with Todd's `iterator`-solution as far as regular removal is concerned. You should however also consider overriding `equals`, because the ID-field seems to be the identifier of your `Element`-class. If you can override `equals`, you can use regular remove.

Comment: midor you're a genius. nice. Thanks todd and midor.

Answer (score 0):

`Premature optimization is the root of all evil  - Donald Knuth`

What the above means in your case is that, unless you have a compelling reason to optimize, do not contemplate optimization.

Comment: I've heard that before. I was more curious on a principle point in general, not in this specific instance. Is it better to create temporary reference or overwrite a reference that is a member of the class, or does it make no difference at all.